# Does the VStack means canvas or ContentView?

Tags: swiftui

When I read the [SwiftUI document](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views)

> Create a new Xcode project that uses SwiftUI. Explore the canvas, previews, and the SwiftUI template code.

Does the `VStack` mean canvas or `ContentView`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VStack` is neither ContentView nor Canvas. According to Apple documentation about [VStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack):

> A view that arranges its subviews in a vertical line.

- ContentView is a view that represents UI. It has a computed property called `body`. In this scenario, the ContentView body returns a VStack as its appearance.
- Canvas, as Apple mentioned on their documentation at [Previews in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/previews-in-xcode) or [Previewing your app’s interface in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/previewing-your-apps-interface-in-xcode), is the entire preview screen on the right hand side of Xcode. It's different with [Canvas](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/canvas) view type.